# STRAPI - one-way one-to-many relationship in content type builder

Tags: strapi

I'm trying to build a simple recipe application using strapi.io's content type builder.

I want to create a lists for recipes and ingredients so I can maintain ingredients, and recipes separately. The hard part is when I need to manage the *quantity* AND the ingredient reference.

Here's sort of what I want to build, if it makes sense? Just can't work out how to do it with the content type builder :(

Simplified version:

```
#recipe
{
    "title" : "beans on toast",
    "ingredients" : [
        {"id" : "beans", "qty" : "1/2 a tin"},
        {"id" : "bread", "qty" : "1 slice"}
    ]
}
#ingredients
{
    "beans" : {"name" : "beans", nutritionalInfo : "makes you fart"},
    "bread" : {"name" : "bread", nutritionalInfo : "good for your heart"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create two collections and add a relation field to each of them. This is the UI for creating relations just replace `appointments` with `ingredients` (left side) and on your right side choose the Ingredient collection and type recipe

[image: UI]